# reading from .txt file into a 2d array

Tags: java

I have txt file  all separated by a space, I know how to read in the file, but I don't know how to place the data into the array

this is the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    try{
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Dash\\Desktop\\itemsset.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = br.readLine();
            String array[][] = null ;
            try {
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    }
                    br.close();
                    fr.close(); 
                }
            catch (IOException exception) {
                System.out.println("Erreur lors de la lecture :"+exception.getMessage());
                }   
        }    
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception){
            System.out.println("Le fichier n'a pas été trouvé");
        }
}
```

Description below :

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a 2D array to me..

Comment: what's the .txt file format? You need to parse the line coming from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have txt file all separated by a space

Read each line, and split it by white space. First, you can construct your file path using the `user.home` system property and relative paths. Something like,

```
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
File f = new File(desktop, "itemsset.txt");
```

Then use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and read each line into a `List<String[]>` like

```
List<String[]> al = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        al.add(line.split("\\s+"));
    }
} catch (IOException exception) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + exception.getMessage());
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can convert your `List<String[]>` into a `String[][]` and display it with [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) like

```
String[][] array = al.toArray(new String[][] {});
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just obsessed by the beauty of Java 8 and it's [Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html).

```
Path p = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"),"Desktop","itemsset.txt");
String [][] twoDee = Files.lines(p)
    .map((line)->line.trim().split("\\s+"))
    .toArray(String[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDee));
```

Similar situations to be found:

- [Read .txt file into 2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185683/read-txt-file-into-2d-array) - I have added an example that does `String []` to `int []` conversion.
- [How do I take a text file and turn it into a 2D array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015934/how-do-i-take-a-text-file-and-turn-it-into-a-2d-array-in-java?lq=1)

Additional Research - [java: convert a list of array into an array of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803619/java-convert-a-list-of-array-into-an-array-of-array)